# Where can I buy a pre-paid SIM card that will work in Andorra?

Tags: cellphones, spain, internet, local-knowledge, andorra

I am landing at the airport in Lleida, Spain and travelling to Pas de la Casa, Andorra. I am new to travelling in general.

I want two SIM cards that will allow me ~8 GB each of internet access, and the ability to make calls between them would be nice as well. I have direct transportation from the airport to the ski resort so I cannot stop and buy anything on the way.

Where can I buy pre-paid SIM cards in Andorra? Which shops usually sell these?

Comment: Andorran SIMs are rediculously expensive (€120 for two sims with 6GiB of data apiece), if you can get a hold of them. It's a pity you aren't coming from France, as Pas de la Casa is just across the border and will have French phone signal. I'm not sure whether there'll be spanish coverage; it's a couple of miles from the spanish border so I wouldn't rely on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Andorra Telecom Wikia](http://prepaid-data-sim-card.wikia.com/wiki/Andorra#)

> [Andorra Telecom](http://www.andorratelecom.ad/web/guest/localitzacio) is the only network provider in this small country. The state owned company was formerly called Servei de Telecomunicacions d'Andorra (STA) a.k.a. Som. It has 2G on 900 and 1800 MHz and 3G/UMTS on 2100 MHz like in most of Europe. 4G/LTE is on 1800 MHz and 800 MHz, but not yet open for prepaid.
>
> Their prepaid product is called Mobiland Clic! You can purchase a SIM card from the Andorra Telecom head office at Av. Merixell 112 in Andorra la Vella or its distributors. Mini-SIMs (2FF), micro-SIMs (3FF), and nano-SIMs (4FF) are available.
>
> A SIM card costs a whopping € 60 including the same credit valid for 5 months. When credit is used up, card stays valid for another 8 months incoming only.
>
> Top-ups can be done with vouchers for € 15, € 30 or € 60 valid for 2, 5 or 7 months respectively available in stores. Check credit by calling 178 for free.
>
> There is no data without packages which have to be booked by sending a SMS. To check the remaining data credit, send a free empty SMS to 123.